# Cosa significa "arreganare"?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Solo Moe, l’ebreo allampanato, è venuto a cercarla. Passava sempre a Prince Street, prima di correre alla scuola serale. S’inventava qualche scusa – che doveva ritoccare il colore della finestra, che voleva aggiungerci un uccello, o la neve sulle montagne. Saliva sulla panca e colorava, mentre Lena, china sull’acquaio proprio sotto di lui, **arreganava** i gamberetti. Moe non la guardava mai e nemmeno le rivolgeva la parola: però restava in quella scomoda posizione finché lei non si spostava, e solo allora scendeva.

Qualcuno di voi saprebbe spiegare il significato di "arreganare"? Non ho trovato questo termine su nessun dizionario. Immagino si tratti di un vocabolo regionale, possibilmente correlato al napoletano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [questo blog di cucina](https://www.google.com/amp/s/blog.giallozafferano.it/incucinaconmara/patate-arracanate-o-gratinate/amp/) si può leggere:

> Patate ***arracanate*** o gratinate: uno tra i contorni piu' diffusi in
>   Puglia. Il termine ***arracanato*** o ***arraganato***, letteralemnte origanato
>   indica una qualsiasi pietanza condita con olio, sale, aglio,
>   prezzemolo, pangrattato e origano cotte con brace sopra e sotto il
>   tegame, quando si cuoceva con le stufe a legna.

In [questo vocabolario napoletano](https://ia800709.us.archive.org/25/items/VolpeVocabolarioNapoletanoItaliano/VolpeVocabolarioNapoletanoItaliano.pdf) si può trovare il termine:

> **Arraganato** - Origanato

In [quest’altro dizionario](http://www.vesuvioweb.com/it/wp-content/uploads/Giuseppe-Giacco-Vocabolario-napoletano-vesuvioweb.pdf) si trova il termine *arraganà*:

> **Arraganà**: tr. cospargere di origano le vivande

Quindi il significato nel contesto da te citato è che Lena stava cospargendo i gamberetti con origano.